# debian apache server slow & not responding - cpu low

Tags: apache-2.2, debian

i have a debian server with apache and mysql installed there.

i have more visitors from 8pm to 22 pm and apache server to slow and lot of times page cant open on this period.

> error: This site can’t be reache   [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) took too long to
> respond.

i check
**htop** and i see low cpu usage , also bandwidh is 1gbps but im not using that much

[CPU - htop command screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wWwTM.png)

[iostat disk write read screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dS8C4.png)

[nload command - traffic screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vFKRY.png)

when i restart with  `service apache2 restart`  it works next few minutes and again same thing

Comment: Additional DB information request, please. Aany SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*), sum(data_length), sum(index_length), sum(data_free) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
Additional very helpful OS information includes - please,  
htop            1st page, if available, TERMINATE, 
top -b -n 1  for most active apps, 
top -b -n 1 -H  for details on your mysql threads memory and cpu usage, 
ulimit -a       for list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device & core/cpu count, 
df -h  for Used - Free space by device, 
df -i  for inode info by device, 
free -h  for Used - Free  Mem: and Swap:, 
cat /proc/meminfo includes VMallocUused,  
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: Please gather the data when your users are experiencing this problem.  Have a SSH login completed early and on standby, please.

Comment: Maybe you can supply the additional information by the end of January for workload analysis.  View profile for contact info.  Thanks